# httpwebrequest gives timeout until restarted

Tags: c#, network-programming, desktop-application

I am working on a desktop application developed in C# (.NET environment).

This application connects to remote server using *HttpWebRequest*. If due to any reason my PC is disconnected from the internet and I re-connect it my application always gives request timeout for *HttpWebRequest* until I restart my whole application and if I again add new thread to my application after network d/c it works fine.

Is there any way to reset my network or anyone can tell me how does it work?

//my code is..

```
public String request(String add, String post, int time, String reff, int id, int rwtime)
    {
        try
        {
            if (rwtime == 0)
            {
                rwtime = 100000;
            }
            string result = "";
            string location = "";
            // Create the web request
            HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(add) as HttpWebRequest;
            req.ReadWriteTimeout = rwtime;
            req.KeepAlive = true;
            req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
            req.Accept = "application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.Timeout = time;
            req.Referer = reff;
            req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            req.CookieContainer = statictk.cc[id];
            req.PreAuthenticate = true;
            if (post != "")
            {
                req.Method = "POST";
                string postData = post;
                ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] byte1 = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
                // Set the content type of the data being posted.
                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                // Set the content length of the string being posted.
                req.ContentLength = byte1.Length;
                Stream newStream = req.GetRequestStream();
                newStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);
                newStream.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                req.Method = "GET";
            }
            // Get response
            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

                // Get the response stream
                location = response.GetResponseHeader("Location");
                if (location == "")
                {
                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    if (response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip"))
                        responseStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
                    else if (response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate"))
                        responseStream = new DeflateStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);

                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);
                    // Read the whole contents and return as a string
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                else
                {
                    result = location;
                }
                response.Close();
                if (result == "") result = "retry";
                return result;
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.store("errorinresponce", e.Message);
                if (statictd.status[id] != "removed")
                {
                    return "retry";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "error";
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception f)
        {
            log.store("Networkerrorretry", f.Message);
            if (f.Message == "The operation has timed out")
            {
                return "retry";
            }
            string ans = MessageBox.Show("There was a Network Error..Wish to Retry ?\nError msg : "+ f.Message, "Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo).ToString();
            if (ans == "Yes")
                return "retry";
            else
            {
                Invoketk.settxt(id, "Not Ready");
                return "error";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your application is missing some error handling. A disconnect can happen at any time and your application should be able to handle it. Try to surround the network loop with a try-catch statement, and then catch for the different kinds of exceptions. Depending on what exception was thrown, you can then decide if you reconnect to the server silently or if you want to generate an error message.